# Adding time to MySQL datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I had an issue where the server time wasn't set to the correct timezone and now need to update the created `datetime` for all users. New users from here on in will be using the correct timezone.

Essentially, I need it to run through all rows in table `users` and update column `created` with + 11 hours

I've tried this but it errors:

```
select `created` FROM `users` + INTERVAL 11 HOUR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a MySQL function [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
UPDATE users SET created = DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 11 HOUR)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sithu, getting error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HOURS)' at line 1"

Comment: @TFK300 Sorry, use `HOUR` without `S`.